# Best approach for threading in GUI application (Java, swing)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

In order to keep the GUI responsive it is necessary to execute long-running tasks, such as database access, on a thread different from the event-dispatch thread. 
To do so, there are two main alternatives: creating a SwingWorker and calling methods of program logic objects (making them trade safe!), or creating a single Thread class and forwarding requests to it (As suggested here: [Java desktop - how to separate database access from the UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955766/java-desktop-how-to-separate-database-access-from-the-ui-thread) ).
Which one and in what cases do you think is a better approach, especially from a design standpoint?

Answer (score 2):

The question is broad and lacks any significant context.

`SwingWorker` is "generally" my preferred solution as it's simple, has multiple ways you can interact with it (`publish`/`process`, `done`, `PropertyListener`) and can be specialised for a unit of work, whether that's a repeated unit of work or a single run case.

`SwingWorker` has limitations, first of all, it will only allow 10 simultaneous workers to be running at a single time, it uses a pool of `Thread`s (for simplicity sake) which it re-uses, but the pool is limited to 10 and there is nothing you can do about it.  This could be an issue if you're anticipating need a lot of concurrent processing to occur, but might not be as big an issue if you just "want the work done" and don't care if some of the work is queued for a period of time.

Using a single `Thread` and queue could work, again, assuming you don't mind that only one piece of work is done at a time and the other task might be queued for a period of time.  The complexity of this approach is setting up the call back process that can return the data/results from the worker `Thread` back to the UI within the context of the EDT, using something like a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) or [Producer/Consumer Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern) in a manner which is flexible enough for you, something that `SwingWorker` already does.

My first thought would be, focus on creating a process by which you can retrieve the data, without worrying about concurrency or the UI.  Once you can establish that, you can then add another, concurrent, layer above it, as not every aspect of your code might care about getting data for the UI.

From there you can devise access mechanisms which your UI code would use to access these two other layers based on your needs.

This is all theory and the context of the overall problem will rule which paths you might follow (or combinations of) (does the database support concurrent access?  Do you want multiple/concurrent access or don't you care? etc).  You can to try and decouple your code in ways which would allow you to change a single layer without having to (significantly) modify the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SwingUtilities.invokeLater()